# Print Output to cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, output

Could someone provide a working example of how I would print to command line the variable fg please.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Foreground {
  class GetForegroundWindowTest {

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
    public static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        IntPtr fg = GetForegroundWindow(); //use fg for some purpose

        /// PRINT fg TO COMMAND LINE

    }
  }
}
```

Part of the Project that this needs to be used on:

The cs file is to be compiled and run in cmd.  The program is to retrieve the name of the users foreground window and output the title of that window to cmd.

I've tried:

```
Console.WriteLine(fg)
```

and

```
[DllImport( "kernel32.dll" )]
static extern bool AttachConsole( int dwProcessId );
private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(fg). Although you may have a GUI app and no console window open. Last time I looked it was too complicated for me to try to open one. You may be better of with a textbox or a dialog with that text in it.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Looking at GetWindowText(), I'm almost afraid the OP wants to dump the _text on the window_, not the window proper. But then that's not much different.

Comment: Robert, just describe clearly what your setup is, what the prog does, what you want to achieve, what you tried, and in which way it failed. "PRINT fg TO COMMAND LINE" and "Could somone provide me with a working example" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't really clear, but I assume you're trying to do this:

```
IntPtr fg = GetForegroundWindow(); //use fg for some purpose

var bufferSize = 1000;
var sb = new StringBuilder(bufferSize);

GetWindowText(fg, sb, bufferSize);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered.  The error was a noob mistake on my part - I was expecting to see command line output at compile stage rather than at .exe stage.  My apologise for all your confusion, on account of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Console.WriteLine(fg);
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(fg) does not print to the command line.  Why might this be?

Comment: What is "the command line"? Are you running in the debugger? Do you have a Windows cmmand window open? Are you under windows at all?? Just be clear and complete in your description.

Comment: I want output to print on cmd

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",fg);
```